# How can i speed up my model training process using tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

My batch size = 128
number of epochs = 15

Single epoch takes 4 hours to complete the task, so the full training process takes a huge time. In my case, I need to increase the speed of my model training process to save my weight values how can I do this

```
# Training Process
results = model.fit_generator(generate_batch(orig_train, forg_train, batch_sz),
                              steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples//batch_sz,
                              epochs = 15,
                              validation_data = generate_batch(orig_val, forg_val, batch_sz),
                              validation_steps = num_val_samples//batch_sz,
                              callbacks = callbacks)
```

and my callback array defined as follows,

```
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=12, verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1),
    ModelCheckpoint('./Weights/model-weight-{epoch:03d}.h5', verbose=1, save_weights_only=True)
]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do:

1. Switch on XLA.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True)
```

2. Switch on mixed precision.

```
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

Comment: Google colab continues processing time limit for12 hours, is there any reason for it??

Comment: The resources are limited, that's why.

Comment: In my research work i have to completed 15 epochs training process in my model, but i still can only train 3 epochs, between 4th epoch it automatically close the session. So i cannot save weight values that provide best validation loss

Comment: I think if i can train 12 epochs (each epoch takes at least 3.30 hours) i can get more accurate result, but i cannot still train after 3rd epoch

Comment: save the model and then, start from the last epoch.

Comment: how i apply your process for my function that i provided in question

Comment: model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_acc',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

Comment: include the above callback in your callbacks array.

Comment: is it only save weight values with best validation accuracy??

Comment: i have added my call back array in question, how can i apply your one to my cqallback array

Comment: Set save_freq='epoch' in the model checkpoint statement. Remove save_best_only.

Comment: in my code i never set save_best_only , so i can't understand your soltuion and how can i apply for my one